# Clear placeholder in the view

Tags: zend-framework, placeholder

I have a Placeholder in my layout, like this:

```
<?php if($this->placeholder('hide_login_form')) : echo new Default_Form_Login(); endif?>
```

But i need remove/clear this placeholder in my view, because i dont need this respective form in another page.

Someone know how i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

From your view, try calling the `set` method of the placeholder with an empty string:

```
$this->placeholder('hide_login_form')->set('');
```

This will replace the value of whatever it contains with an empty value.